# Query by row_number() in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query in raw SQL

```
select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by
"categoryId" order by "updatedAt" desc) as "RowNum", 
"categoryId", "updatedAt" from products as tdr) a
where "RowNum"=1
```

How can I perform the same query in Flask Sqlalchemy?